# Toggling between values while producing events on timer

Tags: system.reactive, xna-4.0

I'm playing with using the Rx in an XNA proof-of-concept, and I've run into a bit of an obstacle composing some queries that I'm hoping you folks can assist me with understanding how some of these operators work.

In my POC, I would like the player's score to increment only while there is not an active drag operation occurring. In addition, there is a 'grab gauge' that I would like to deplete whenever there is an ongoing drag, and fill whenever there isn't. Finally, if a drag operation is under way and the grab gauge drops below 0, I want to cancel the drag operation.

I've got the score incrementing working just fine with this:

```
 IObservable<bool> PrincessGrabbed; // e.g., OnGrabbedBegin
 _playerScoreChanged = IObservable<Unit>
// ... //

// In the initialization method
_playerScoreChanged = from startTrigger in PrincessGrabbed.StartWith(false)
                                                          .Where(x => !x)
                      from i in Observable.Interval(TargetElapsedTime)
                                          .TakeUntil(PrincessGrabbed
                                                       .Where(x => x)
                      select new Unit(); 

_playerScoreChanged.Subscribe(unit => PlayerScore += 1);
```

The score will increment when it is supposed to, and stop when the character is picked up. Getting the gauge behavior to work correctly has been troublesome however. I've tried a ton of variations using `Window`, `Generate`, etc... but what seems to end up happening is that either it doesn't work at all, or the increment/decrement gauge operations end up fighting each other, or it will all seem to work properly, but continue to subtract or add points/gauge in the background. Here's the gauge implementation (extremely poor performance, crashes after about 10-15s, doesn't work properly):

```
var a = from startTrigger in PrincessGrabbed.StartWith(false).Where(x => x)
                from i in Observable.Interval(TargetElapsedTime)
                    .Where(x => GrabGaugeFillAmount > 0)
                    .TakeUntil(PrincessGrabbed.Where(x => !x))
                select new Unit();

a.TimeInterval().Subscribe(unit => 
            GrabGaugeFillAmount -= (float)unit.Interval.TotalSeconds * 
                GrabGaugeDepletionPerSecond);
```

I have no doubts that my lack of understanding with Rx is at fault in some way, shape, or form, but I've reached the limit of experimenting with different operators/queries. Any insights?

---

EPILOGUE: Gideon Engelberth's answer fit my needs spot-on - I wish I could upvote it 10x! Here's the quick C# representation of his answer (not 100% on the IDisposable.Dispose(), but should be close):

```
public class AlternatingSubject : IDisposable
{
    private readonly object _lockObj = new object();

    private int _firstTriggered;

    private readonly ISubject<Unit> _first = new Subject<Unit>();
    public ISubject<Unit> First { get { return _first; }}

    private readonly ISubject<Unit> _second = new Subject<Unit>();
    public ISubject<Unit> Second { get { return _second; }}

    public void TriggerFirst()
    {
        if (System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(ref _firstTriggered, 1) == 1)
            return;

        First.OnNext(Unit.Default);
    }

    public void TriggerSecond()
    {
        if (System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(ref _firstTriggered, 0) == 0)
            return;

        Second.OnNext(Unit.Default);
    }

    #region Implementation of IDisposable
    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            First.OnCompleted();
            Second.OnCompleted();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And the logic to hook up the events in the game class (there are some refactoring opportunities). Summary: works like a charm! Thanks!

```
public class PrincessCatcherGame : Game
{
    // ... //
    public IObservable<bool> PrincessGrabbed // external source fires these events
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return princessGrabbed.AsObservable();
        }
    } 
    // ... //
    private readonly ISubject<bool> _princessGrabbed = new Subject<bool>();
    private readonly ISubject<Unit> _grabGaugeEmptied = new Subject<Unit>();
    private readonly ISubject<Unit> _grabGaugeFull = new Subject<Unit>();
    private readonly AlternatingSubject _alternatingSubject = new AlternatingSubject();
    private ISubject<Unit> _grabs;
    private ISubject<Unit> _releases;
    // ... //
    private void SubscribeToGrabbedEvents()
    {
        var decrements = from g in _grabs
                         from tick in Observable.Interval(TargetElapsedTime).TakeUntil(_releases)
                         select Unit.Default;
        decrements.Subscribe(x =>
                                 {
                                     Debug.Assert(GrabGaugeFillAmount >= 0);
                                     GrabGaugeFillAmount -= (GrabGaugeDepletionPerSecond/30f);
                                     if (GrabGaugeFillAmount <= 1)
                                     {
                                         GrabGaugeFillAmount = 0;
                                         _alternatingSubject.TriggerSecond();
                                         _grabGaugeEmptied.OnNext(Unit.Default);
                                     }
                                 });
        decrements.Subscribe(x => PlayerScore += 1);

        var increments = from r in _releases
                         from tick in Observable.Interval(TargetElapsedTime).TakeUntil(_grabs.Merge(_grabGaugeFull))
                         select Unit.Default;
        increments.Subscribe(x =>
                                 {
                                     Debug.Assert(GrabGaugeFillAmount <= 100);
                                     GrabGaugeFillAmount += (GrabGaugeFillPerSecond/30f);
                                     if (GrabGaugeFillAmount >= 100)
                                     {
                                         GrabGaugeFillAmount = 100;
                                         _grabGaugeFull.OnNext(Unit.Default);
                                     }
                                 });
    }
```

Comment: About the dispose, I actually just dispose the two subjects.  Most disposes end up being just "dispose all the non-null disposable fields", which is why I left it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track.  I would start by making grabs and releases observables of their own and then making `PrincessGrabbed` based on those two observables.  For a case like this, I use a class I call `AlternatingSubject`.

```vb
Public NotInheritable Class AlternatingSubject
    Implements IDisposable
    'IDisposable implementation left out for sample

    Private _firstTriggered As Integer

    Private ReadOnly _first As New Subject(Of Unit)()
    Public ReadOnly Property First As IObservable(Of Unit)
        Get
            Return _first
        End Get
    End Property

    Private ReadOnly _second As New Subject(Of Unit)()
    Public ReadOnly Property Second As IObservable(Of Unit)
        Get
            Return _second
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub TriggerFirst()
        If System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(_firstTriggered, 1) = 1 Then Exit Sub
        _first.OnNext(Unit.Default)
    End Sub

    Public Sub TriggerSecond()
        If System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(_firstTriggered, 0) = 0 Then Exit Sub
        _second.OnNext(Unit.Default)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Along with that, you will probably want to add a "gague full" observable you can trigger from the incrementing method.  The "gague empty" will trigger the release portion of the AlternatingSubject.

```vb
Sub Main()
    Dim alt As New AlternatingSubject
    Dim grabs = alt.First
    Dim releases = alt.Second
    Dim isGrabbed As New Subject(Of Boolean)()

    'I assume you have these in your real app, 
    'simulate them with key presses here
    Dim mouseDowns As New Subject(Of Unit)
    Dim mouseUps As New Subject(Of Unit)

    Dim gagueFulls As New Subject(Of Unit)()

    'the TakeUntils ensure that the timers stop ticking appropriately
    Dim decrements = From g In grabs
                     From tick In Observable.Interval(TargetElapsedTime) _
                                    .TakeUntil(releases)
                     Select Unit.Default
    'this TakeUnitl watches for either a grab or a gague full
    Dim increments = From r In releases
                     From tick In Observable.Interval(TargetElapsedTime) _
                                    .TakeUntil(grabs.Merge(gagueFulls))
                     Select Unit.Default

    'simulated values for testing, you may just have
    'these be properties on an INotifyPropertyChanged object
    'rather than having a PlayerScoreChanged observable.
    Const GagueMax As Integer = 20
    Const GagueMin As Integer = 0
    Const GagueStep As Integer = 1
    Dim gagueValue As Integer = GagueMax
    Dim playerScore As Integer

    Dim disp As New CompositeDisposable()
    'hook up IsGrabbed to the grabs and releases
    disp.Add(grabs.Subscribe(Sub(v) isGrabbed.OnNext(True)))
    disp.Add(releases.Subscribe(Sub(v) isGrabbed.OnNext(False)))
    'output grabbed state to the console for testing
    disp.Add(isGrabbed.Subscribe(Sub(v) Console.WriteLine("Grabbed: " & v)))
    disp.Add(gagueFulls.Subscribe(Sub(v) Console.WriteLine("Gague full")))


    disp.Add(decrements.Subscribe(Sub(v)
                                      'testing use only
                                      If gagueValue <= GagueMin Then
                                          Console.WriteLine("Should not get here, decrement below min!!!")
                                      End If

                                      'do the decrement
                                      gagueValue -= GagueStep
                                      Console.WriteLine("Gague value: " & gagueValue.ToString())
                                      If gagueValue <= GagueMin Then
                                          gagueValue = GagueMin
                                          Console.WriteLine("New gague value: " & gagueValue)
                                          alt.TriggerSecond() 'trigger a release when the gague empties
                                      End If
                                  End Sub))
    disp.Add(decrements.Subscribe(Sub(v)
                                      'based on your example, it seems you score just for grabbing
                                      playerScore += 1
                                      Console.WriteLine("Player Score: " & playerScore)
                                  End Sub))
    disp.Add(increments.Subscribe(Sub(v)
                                      'testing use only
                                      If gagueValue >= GagueMax Then
                                          Console.WriteLine("Should not get here, increment above max!!!")
                                      End If

                                      'do the increment
                                      gagueValue += GagueStep
                                      Console.WriteLine("Gague value: " & gagueValue.ToString())
                                      If gagueValue >= GagueMax Then
                                          gagueValue = GagueMax
                                          Console.WriteLine("New gague value: " & gagueValue)
                                          gagueFulls.OnNext(Unit.Default) 'trigger a full
                                      End If
                                  End Sub))
    'hook the "mouse" to the grab/release subject
    disp.Add(mouseDowns.Subscribe(Sub(v) alt.TriggerFirst()))
    disp.Add(mouseUps.Subscribe(Sub(v) alt.TriggerSecond()))

    'mouse simulator
    Dim done As Boolean
    Do
        done = False
        Dim key = Console.ReadKey()
        If key.Key = ConsoleKey.G Then
            mouseDowns.OnNext(Unit.Default)
        ElseIf key.Key = ConsoleKey.R Then
            mouseUps.OnNext(Unit.Default)
        Else
            done = True
        End If
    Loop While Not done
    'shutdown
    disp.Dispose()
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

For the sake of the test app, everything is in one function.  In your real app, you should of course consider what to expose and how.

Comment: I like the Alternating Subject approach. I'll give it a go and post back here how it turns out

Comment: ok holy frijole it's rare to just drop something in and have it 'just work', but that's what happened! Posting in answer edit