# Using Rx to execute delayed action once with cancellation for each window

Tags: .net, system.reactive

specifically I am trying to simulate performing an action if the key is held down for a duration greater than Threshold (T).

I am trying to do this using Reactive Extensions .NET (The stable 1.0 version) **without state variables.**

Here's the marble diagram of my inputs and what I need:

let T = 3 (so 4 dddd without a key up event make up a "key held down")

keyDown: --dddd---dd--d-dddddddddd----

keyUp:   -----------u-----u--u---------------u--

desired: --------a---------------a----------

Here's some example code I came up with that works but uses a state variable.

```
var keyDownStream = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventArgs>(this, "KeyDown").Where(args => args.EventArgs.Key == Key.OemPeriod);
        var keyUpStream = Observable.FromEventPattern<KeyEventArgs>(this, "KeyUp").Where(args => args.EventArgs.Key == Key.OemPeriod);

        var repeatGuard = false;
        keyUpStream.Subscribe(x => repeatGuard = false);
        keyDownStream
            .DelayOrCancel(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0), keyUpStream)
            .Where(_ => repeatGuard == false)
            .Do(_ =>
            {
                repeatGuard = true;
            })
            .Subscribe(
                result =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("KeyHold");
                }
            );

public static class JustinsRx
{
    public static IObservable<T> DelayOrCancel<T, TCancel>(this IObservable<T> source,
                                     TimeSpan delay,
                                     IObservable<TCancel> cancel)
    {
        //argument checking skipped
        return from s in source
               from i in Observable.Timer(delay).TakeUntil(cancel)
               select s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Progress update:  I'm attempting this query, but it is actually blocking the caller!  Anyone know why this is blocking the caller so the window doesn't even display?

            keyDownStream
                .DelayOrCancel(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), keyUpStream)
                .Window(()=>keyUpStream)
                .Subscribe(result =>
                  {
                      if (result.First() == result.Last())
                        Console.WriteLine("KeyHold");
                      //do stuff 
                  });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but I feel that it could be made shorter.

```
var firstKeyDowns = Observable
    .Merge(keyDownStream.Select(_ => 'd'), keyUpStream.Select(_ => 'u'))
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Where(c => c == 'd');
var query = from s in firstKeyDowns 
            from i in Observable.Timer(delay).TakeUntil(keyUpStream)
            select s;
```

EDIT: Here's a different version that I think is a bit nicer:

```
var noRepeats = Observable
    .Merge(keyDownStream.Select(_ => 'd'), keyUpStream.Select(_ => 'u'))
    .DistinctUntilChanged();
var query = noRepeats
    .Throttle(delay)
    .Where(c => c == 'd');
```

Comment: +1 This is probably as short as it gets and is a decent use of the built-in operators to do it.  Alternatively, something like [AlternatingSubject](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9445579/174594) could do the input filtering before passing to DelayOrCancel.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I'll take a look at yours and Enigmativity's solutions and I'll give the correct answer to whomever's solution actually works exactly like my marble diagram/code example without side affects.  If both work, then I'll base it on performance.  Thanks again!  Give me a couple hours and I'll get back to you guys.

Comment: Hands down winner!  Great solution man, I can see it even performs far better than my stateful code due to the use of DistinctUntilChanged.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
var timer = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));

var query =
    keyDownStream
        .Select(_ =>
            keyUpStream
                .Select(_ => 'u')
                .Amb(timer.Select(_ => 't'))
                .Take(1)
                .Where(x => x == 'u')
                .Select(_ => Unit.Default))
        .Switch();
```

Comment: this does not even come close :)

Comment: @JustinMoser - How so? It seemed to meet the requirements. Can you let me know what didn't work?

Comment: Sorry I didn't think you tested it, since it does not compile.  The reason it does not work is because the OnNext doesn't happen until the keyUp event occurs---due to the "Where(x => x == 'u')".  Fixing this query is not trivial.  (You can't just remove the where, because then there are other problems such as the OnNext will trigger for every keyDown event, as opposed to only the first one after the duration.